# Inputing values into next blank row + Validity checks for textboxes VBA-UserForm

Tags: vba, cell, spreadsheet, userform

So im writing a program for my coursework and im pretty stuck ive got all my values inputed in the correct cells but i want to make sure that if a row is free inbetween the ones already there the code will be input there. So far its just looking for last row and putting it there even if there is a space inbetween.

```
Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Details")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row

ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Forename.Value 'Adds the TextBox into Col A & Last Blank Row
ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Surname.Value
ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = School.Value
ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Candidate.Value
```

This is what i have which works. Also how can i make sure that if the user puts a special character such as "!"£$%^&*(){}[]:;@'~#?><,./|\" or a number within a textbox to show a message box saying its incorrect i did it for numbers but dont know how to do it for this.

```
If Len(Candidate.Value) > 4 Then
MsgBox "The Candidate number is too long"
End If

If IsNumeric(Candidate.Value) = False Then
MsgBox "Candidate number contains characters other than numbers"
End If
```

Thanks in advance look forward to seeing your replies

This is the whole code for the submit button

```
Private Sub Submit_click()
      'Output all information into the spreadsheet

If Forename.Value = "" Then
    Me.Forename.SetFocus
    MsgBox "The Forename is Missing"        'Validation Check - Makes sure the Value is not empty
End If

If Surname.Value = "" Then
    Me.Surname.SetFocus
    MsgBox "The Surname is Missing"         'Validation Check - Makes sure the Value is not empty
End If

If School.Value = "" Then
    Me.School.SetFocus
    MsgBox "The School you previously attended to is Missing"          'Validation Check - Makes sure the Value is not empty
End If

If Candidate.Value = "" Then
    Me.Candidate.SetFocus
    MsgBox "The Candidate number is Missing"         'Validation Check - Makes sure the Value is not empty
End If

If IsNumeric(Candidate.Value) = False Then
    MsgBox "Candidate number contains characters other than numbers"        'Validation Check - makes sure only numbers are entered
End If

If Trim(Me.Candidate.TextLength > 4) Then
    Me.Candidate.SetFocus
    MsgBox ("Candidate Number Contains more than 4 characters")   'Validation Check - Makes sure that no more than 4 characters are entered
End If

If Trim(Me.Candidate.TextLength < 4) Then
    Me.Candidate.SetFocus
    MsgBox ("Candidate Number Contains less than 4 characters")       'Validation Check - Makes sure that no less than 4 characters are entered
End If

Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Details")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Finds the last blank row

'This is the stuff i had before that are quoted out i dont know what to use

'ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Forename.Value 'Adds the TextBox into Col A & Last Blank Row
'ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Forename.Value
'ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Surname.Value
'ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = School.Value
'ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Candidate.Value

 'Sub fillstuff()

Range("A:a").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Forename"
Range("A:a").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 1).Value = "Surname"
Range("A:a").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 2).Value = "School"
Range("A:a").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 3).Value = "Candidate"
```

This is all the stuff i have underneath my submit button all the validation checks work they all give messages but the last code after the quote where i mentioned doesnt work at all. What do i need to do in order to make that work

Comment: put ws. in front of offset stuff. Honestly you should have more than enough to figure this out now :)

Comment: Range("A:a").End(xlDown).ws.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Forename"         like this

Answer (score 0):

Ya killin me smalls <3

Here is everything you asked for in the order it should probably look in your module/userform code. Since youre new to this it is worth pointing out that the order of execution matters. Once you start working with larger object sets and more complicated types of calculations, trouble shooting often entails figuring out where what value was set in the execution order. That was probably the biggest headache for in my first larger macro set.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim somestuff As somestuff

'this checks textbox1 for more than 4 digits in length
 If Trim(Me.TextBox1.TextLength > 4) Then
     Me.TextBox.SetFocus
     MsgBox ("you have entered more than 4 characters")
     Exit Sub
 End If

'Some other code
'more code to do stuff

Range("A:a").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Forename"
Range("A:a").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 1).Value = "Surname"
Range("A:a").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 2).Value = "School"
Range("A:a").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 3).Value = "Candidate"

'This makes the userform "disappear" after execution. Might Not be needed for your purpose
Unload Me

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()

'as a habit i tend to create "clear" command buttons as well
TextBox1.Value = vbNullString
TextBox2.Value = vbNullString 'also its a good habit to use vbNullString instead of ""

End Sub
```

---

```
'this prevents user from entering nonnumerics in textbox 1
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
     Select Case KeyAscii
       Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyBack, vbKeyClear, vbKeyLeft, _
  vbKeyRight, vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyTab
       Case Else
         KeyAscii = 0
         Beep
     End Select
End Sub
```

---

```
  'this assumes that the text box for letters only is a different text box. You would_
     ' need to duplicate this type of data validation per text box
     Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
          If (KeyAscii < 65 Or KeyAscii > 90) And (KeyAscii < 97 Or KeyAscii > 122) Then KeyAscii = 0
     End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot as i dont need those validations now apart from the amount ones. by the way is there a way of limiting the user to only input no more than 4 numbers within this code. What would be the change between this and lets say if i was to limit someone from only being allowed to put in letters

Comment: I know that i would probably have to do vbKeyA to vbKeyZ instead of vbKey0 to vbKey9 but what else do i need to change as its not letting me put in anything if i only change that

Comment: let me look into more and get back to you @KarolKowalczyk

Comment: @KarolKowalczyk  I think this should be more than satisfactory

Comment: Thanks man that is excellent helps soo much. Got a question though within the userform initialize i set focus to one of my text fields being forename when i press tab it then goes straight to submit then reset and then close then to surname and the text boxes as follows. How can i change this  @DougCoats

Comment: You can set tab order in your useform by right clicking your userform. Also if this answers your question please give me some rep and check mark it as answered

Comment: Yeah i did that it partly answered my question because i still need help with finding the next available column in a spreadsheet, like the first part of my question asks

Comment: ah i added some offset logic for you

Comment: hi i just replaced my code with yours and it seems to still be going to the last available row it doesnt seem to find an empty row inbetween so what i mean is that if i have 10 rows from row 2-10 all full with details and row 5 is empty it puts all the data into row 11 instead of row 5

Comment: Hi sorry but i am kind off new to vba more like a beginner how do i paste this code in as in how is it ment to look. the userform has a submit button which is what it would be under its called private sub Submit_Click() underneath it has a few validation checks such as

If Forename.Value = "" Then
Me.Forename.SetFocus
MsgBox "The Forename is Missing"
End If

ive got this for all of my boxes and then underneath is where i have the submit instructions as to where to put it where would i add that piece of code

Comment: Hi, I changed the question above and included my whole code for the submit button and the code that is used to output into the spreadsheet doesnt work